# How to get a value from an array using a function that doesn't fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function to get the data returned as follows:

```js
async function getAccessToken () {
  let accessTokenInit = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken()
  let accessToken = JSON.stringify(accessTokenInit)
  return accessToken
}
```

It will return the following array:
[image]

And this is the code I need to get the accesstoken value in "token": value but I try to return accessToken.data.access_token but it doesn't work...

```js
  email: {
    provider: env(`${process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_PROVIDER}`),
    providerOptions: {
      host: env("EMAIL_SMTP_HOST", "smtp.gmail.com"),
      port: env("EMAIL_SMTP_PORT", 587),
      auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: "hjhjhj1i2i@gmail.com",
        clientId: `"${process.env.CLIENT_ID }"`,
        clientSecret: `${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}`,
        refreshToken: `${process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN}`,
        accessToken: await getAccessToken(),       
      },
    },
    }
```

So is there a way for me to get the value and assign it to acessToken?

Comment: `getAccessToken()` is returning a string. Cannot get object properties from a string...

Comment: any solution for me?

Comment: Umm... Don't convert it to a string?

Comment: Can i ask more, why when i remove async await in export module, it gives this error Error sending email to trungsoobin10@gmail.com {"errno":-4078,"code":"ESOCKET"," syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":587,"command":"CONN"}

Answer (score 1):

```
async function getAccessToken() {
  const accessTokenInit = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken();
  return accessTokenInit.token;
}
```

Or you can directly return the response if you are not using in this wrapper function:

```
async function getAccessToken() {
  return (await oauth2Client.getAccessToken()).token;
}
```

The mistake i think you were doing was that you are converting an object to a string and using whole that string in token i.e you have all the object.

Comment: Can i ask more, why when i remove async await in export module, it gives this error Error sending email to trungsoobin10@gmail.com {"errno":-4078,"code":"ESOCKET"," syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":587,"command":"CONN"}

Comment: If you remove the await then the oauth2Client.getAccessToken() promise is not resolved (or rejected).